# How to check if multidimensional array is empty or not in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to check if there is an empty array in the nested arrays.

This is what I get from my form.

```
array:15 [▼
  "_token" => "h4aR4xJlWhZveRKbAgHzgzHWSKSqyhVKb7OHAgWH"
  "name" => "Test office"
  "is_department" => "0"
  "hours" => "1-3"
  "description" => "Description"
  "content" => "<p>Content</p>"
  "street" => "123 Street"
  "city" => "Foomania"
  "state" => "Sweet state"
  "postal" => "98234"
  "phone" => "5748293212"
  "fax" => "2123131233"
  "email" => "test@domain.tld"
  "additional-page" => ""
  "office_fees" => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "description" => ""
      "fee" => ""
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "description" => ""
      "fee" => ""
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "description" => ""
      "fee" => ""
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "description" => ""
      "fee" => ""
    ]
  ]
]
```

How can I check if there is empty array in `office_fees` ?

Just to be clear, `office_fees` will always return at least one array. What I'm trying to is to be able to determine whether the `office_fees` need to be saved into another model.

Comment: I have tried with ```array_collapse``` to make the multidimensional array into single array and checked my key is empty or not. I guess, this might be the solution to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what You're looking for but:

`empty($data['office_fees'])`

checks if an array isset and not empty. If You want to check an empty array try this:

`if (is_array($data['office_fees']) && !empty($data['office_fees']))`

Comment: I would like to check whether any of the 'description' or 'fee' is empty. currently, this will always return ```true``` as I will always get array within the 'office_fees'

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.2 you can validate arrays

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'office_fees.*.description' => 'required',
]);
```

Source: [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays)